# How do I implement a workflow system that involves approval of a users in django rest framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a leave model class that has the following definitions below. I would like to create some sort of work flow where after the employee applies for a leave after entering the required fields. He/She will be redirected to a `pending` url. which will show the details of the applied leave. Then there after will the supervisor approve or decline the leave. Any Ideas of how I can Implement this in the views using `class based`  views? You will also see below of how I have Implemented this in the views.

```
class Leave(models.Model):

    """ Vacation timesheet model """
    LEAVE_STATUS_APPROVED = 1
    LEAVE_STATUS_REJECTED = 2
    LEAVE_STATUS_PENDING = 3

    LEAVE_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (LEAVE_STATUS_APPROVED, 'approved'),
        (LEAVE_STATUS_REJECTED, 'rejected'),
        (LEAVE_STATUS_PENDING, 'pending'),
    )

    leave_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, related_name='applicant', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    approver = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, related_name='approver', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    applied_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    responded_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    leave_type = models.ForeignKey(LeaveType, null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rejected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    return_date = models.DateField()
    leave_status = models.CharField(max_length=80,
                                    choices=LEAVE_STATUS_CHOICES,
                                    default=LEAVE_STATUS_PENDING)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    leave_subject = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    leave_reason = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    total_days = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'LeaveApplication'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee) + "__" + self.leave_type + "__" + self.id



class LeaveApplyAPI(APIView):

    """
        {   "applicant":1,
            "approver":1,
            "leave_type":1,
            "leave_subject":"Sick Off",
            "leave_reason":"Sick",
            "start_date":"YY-MM-DD",
            "return_date":"YY-MM-DD"
        }
    """

    lookup_field = 'pk'
    # permission_classes = (permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions,)
    serializer_class = ApplyLeaveSerializer

    def total_days(self, start_date, return_date):
        oneday = timedelta(days=1)
        # convert str to datetime
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        return_date = datetime.strptime(return_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        total_days = 0
        while (start_date <= return_date):
            if not start_date.isoweekday() in (6, 7):
                total_days += 1
            start_date += oneday
        return total_days

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        leaves = Leave.objects.all()
        serializer = ApplyLeaveSerializer(leaves, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)

        start_date = request.data.get('start_date')
        return_date = request.data.get('return_date')
        total_days = self.total_days(start_date, return_date)

        applicant = Employee.objects.get(id=request.data.pop('applicant'))

        approver = Employee.objects.get(id=request.data.pop('approver'))

        leave_type = LeaveType.objects.get(id=request.data.pop('leave_type'))
        leave_subject = request.data.get('leave_subject')
        leave_reason = request.data.get('leave_reason')

        leave = Leave.objects.create(**request.data)
        leave.total_days = total_days
        leave.applicant = applicant
        leave.approver = approver
        leave.leave_type = leave_type
        leave.leave_subject = leave_subject
        leave.leave_reason = leave_reason
        leave.save()

        serializer = ApplyLeaveSerializer(leave)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your views into a `LeaveApplyView` and a `LeaveApproveView` and two corresponding serializers as well

You'll can have two serializers; the `LeaveApplySerializer` and `LeaveApproveSerializer`, with the fields set to read-only as applicable. For example (since I don't have the actual serializer definition, I am using my own:

This is an example of the apply serializer where the fields to be edited such as reason/type are editable, and other fields are read-only

```
class LeaveApplySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Leave
        fields = (
            'leave_id',
            'applied_on',
            .
            .
            .
            'total_days',
        )
        read_only_fields = (  # Make the fields that the applicant can't edit read-only
            'approver',
            'approved',
            'rejected',
            'comment',  # If this is an appoval field   
        )
```

This is an example of the approve serializer where the fields to be edited such as approved/rejected are editable, and other fields are read-only

```
class LeaveApproveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Leave
            fields = (
                .
                .
                .
            )
            read_only_fields = (  # Make the fields that the appover can't edit read-only
                'applicant',
                'leave_type'
                .
                .
                .
            )
```

Finally, flesh out two separate views for approvals and applications; or dynamically select the right serailizer based on the user/action type for the view.

You can then use a custom `permission_class` on the `LeaveApproveView` to only allow the Approver to edit this model

```
class LeaveApproverPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        """
        Return `True` if the user us an approver for the leave.
        """
        return request.user == obj.approver.user
```

One suggestions: It appears that the Leave and Approvals are fairly non-overlapping and you might stand to benefit from separating them at a model level. Why not have two models:

`class Leave` and `class LeaveApproval` that have a `OneToOneField` mapping between them?

Comment: I think your suggestion would be a great idea doing so.